# .hover for dropdown elements (the results) in select2

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Is it possible to fire an event or to add a class to a result element from the select2?

I mean there is the possibility to add classes with `containerCssClass` `dropdownCssClass` these provide the ability to add classes to the given element. But I want to add at least a class to the result items. For clarifying, those are the elements in the dropdown element.

The final usage for this is to have a .hover for the highlighted element. By hovering over it there will be some more information shown in a seperate div about the highlighted element before the user clicks on it to select it. This is because some results have the same basic data while the detailed data differs. Adding this in the results would make it too large in width and make it look chaotic so the cleanest solution would be a seperate div.

Ideally I would want to change the div if the mouse hovers over the result element for at least .5 seconds. This is due to an ajax call that takes place.

I am using select2 3.5.2.

*Edit:
For the bounty I meant within bootstrap, not zf2.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20187032/how-do-enable-hover-event-on-select2-choice

Comment: While this answer solved the issue of his version in select2, it isn't compatible with the version I am using. I'd rather not modify the library for when we upgrade to a newer version to not face the same issues again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot digging in the select2.js and many guidelines I came to the option **formatResult**. There isn't a clear documentation for this (at least I couldn't find one), but what it basically does is that it allows the user to store additional data to a result. These would normally be plain text in a "li". Using this function allows you to modify what is in it.

With a work around for my specific case I inserted a span with an onmouseover and onmouseleave event with a custom id and attributes.

The onmouseover triggers a function that creates a function with a timeout of 1 second. After the 1 second the div gets updated with attributes from the earlier created span.

The onmouseleave sets the timeout function on null, meaning that the div won't get updated at all that contains the extra data.

Hopefully this solution will save people out there plenty of time.

*This solution doesn't need a modification in the select2 library.*